# ArduinoSketchUploader (a nuget package built in C#) use in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, arduino

I am trying to use a nuget package [ArduinoSketchUploader](https://github.com/twinearthsoftware/ArduinoSketchUploader) built in C# in to a Visual Basic code. I have converted this C# code given on their Github page in to VB.

C# code

```
var upload = new ArduinoSketchUploader(
new ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions()
{ 
    FileName = @"location of the file",
    PortName = "COM7",
    ArduinoModel = ArduinoModel.Micro
});

upload.UploadSketch();
```

VB code:

```
  Dim uploader As ArduinoSketchUploader  
                (
                 New ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions()  
                {
                    FileName = @"C:\MyHexFiles\UnoHexFile.ino.hex",
                    PortName = "COM3",
                    ArduinoModel = ArduinoModel.UnoR3
                }
                );

            uploader.UploadSketch()
```

The code works fine in a C# project but the VB converted code doesn't work in a VB project. Am I making mistake in code conversion or its not possible to use C# library in a VB project?

Thanks

Comment: The C# library is compiled down to MSIL and run in .NET (Framework) runtime anyways. Could you post the error you get when trying to convert the project ? I would just try to use the library nuget package as it is and post the errors you still get ? It might be you are using the wrong version, framework version or missing some references. .NET is supposed to work with mixing languages, such as C#, VB or F# and other languages that can compile down to MSIL intermediate language.

Comment: Yes, you are making mistakes in your code conversion, if it's exactly as posted.  It needs to be either `Dim uploader As New ArduinoSketchUploader ...` or `Dim uploader = New ArduinoSketchUploader ...`.  Also, no semicolon at the end of a line in VB, no `@` for a verbatim string (VB doesn't use backslashes for escapes), and I think you need `With` before the braces and a prefix `.` on each of the properties so initialized.  If you're writing this in Visual Studio, it should give you some red squigglies to flag syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you ToreAurstad and @Craig, answer from Mohi Solved the problem. yes its code conversion problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# Class Library (DLL) likewise it is VB. They are simply the same only the program code which is used to build it is different.

The same if you use a green and a red screwdriver to fix something.

So **Is it possible to use the C# library in a VB project?** Yes, Assuming the C# code is CLS compliant, you can simply add a reference of it to your VB.Net project.

And regarding your code, the way you instantiate a class is different in both languages, I think this is what you need:

```
Imports ArduinoUploader
Imports ArduinoUploader.Hardware

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim options As New ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions
        options.ArduinoModel = ArduinoModel.Micro
        options.FileName = "C:\MyHexFiles\UnoHexFile.ino.hex"
        options.PortName = "COM3"

        Dim uploader As New ArduinoSketchUploader(options)

        uploader.UploadSketch()

    End Sub
End Module
```

For more information checkout [CLS-Compliant Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bhc3fa7f(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved but I am getting an exception on uploader.UploadSketch(). Exception:  Unable to aqcuire sync in SendWithSyncRetry for request of type ArduinoUploader.BootloaderProgrammers.Protocols.STK500v1.Messages.ReadSignatureRequest!
Do you have any idea about it? Thank you

Comment: That's another question which not relate to this one. you can ask another question and wait for answers from the community.